# How to set seaborn.pairplot legend fontsize

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to set the fontsize of the legend, which is automatically generated by using keyword `hue` in seaborn.pairplot:

```
g = seaborn.pairplot(df, hue='parameters', diag_kind = 'kde', palette={'r', 'g'},
                plot_kws = {'alpha': 0.6, 's': 80, 'edgecolor': 'k'},
                size = 4)
```

does anybody know the way of setting the fontsize of this legend (automatically generated by `hue`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution by using `matplotlib.pyplot`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rc('legend',fontsize=25, title_fontsize=15)
```

maybe there is another (built-in in seaborn) way of setting these parameters.